# Redirection not working with .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I am using htaccess to hide GET variables from the URL. I am having a problem. Myy project structure is something like this:

```
--project

  index.php

  /views

    login.php

    example.php

    /user

      dashboard.php
```

So, when I use something like "localhost/project/login", I am correctly redirected to the login.php page. But when I do something like "localhost/project/user/dashboard", I get an Apache generated 404 Not Found response.

[image: Error message]

This is what I am using in PHP to include the pages with the GET variables:

PHP code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
$page = $_GET['page'].'.php';
if(is_file('views/'.$page)) {
    include 'views/'.$page;
} else {
    echo 'Page does not exist';
}
?>
```

htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

Can anybody give me some guidance? I don't have experience with .htaccess files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
> ```

I'm assuming your `.htaccess` file is located in the `/project` subdirectory (for the `localhost/project/login` URL to be successfully matched and routed by your PHP code).

However, the regex in the `RewriteRule` directive does not match the request `localhost/project/user/dashboard`, because the regex does not match `user/dashboard` since the regex does not permit slashes (except at the end of URL-path). So the request simply drops through to an Apache 404.

You need to permit slashes in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, which you could do by including a slash inside the character class. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([/A-Za-z0-9-]+?)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

The `+` quantifier needs to be made non-greedy so as not to consume the optional trailing slash.

NB: The `NC` flag is not required here, but the `L` flag is (if you later add more directives).

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. Your solution worked for me. But now the path of the .js and .css files seems to be wrong. I am including those files in the index.php, shouldn't those files be correctly loaded. Now, when I check the path of one of them, I get this, for example: "http://localhost/project/user/dashboard/js/jquery.min.js".

Comment: Does this mean I should use absolute paths instead?

Comment: @ErinFrost Yes, you need to use absolute or root-relative URL-paths for your static resources (CSS, JS, images, etc.). See the following question on Webmasters SE: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css

Comment: Great. I will take a look at that link. I have one last question: Once I am in one of those paths, example: "http://localhost/project/user/dashboard/", and I want to send more GET variables, how could I handle that in the .htaccess file? Let's say I want to add "?gender=male". How could I also hide that GET variable or more GET variables once I am in "http://localhost/project/user/dashboard/"?